# Error with magento after extension uninstall

Tags: product, backend

I tried out the instagram extension , and it didt work. I then wanted to uninstall it. 
I did.

When i try to edit a product now i get this  (from log file ) :

```
2014-06-21T21:13:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Instagramconnect/Model/Source/Instagram/User.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/7/w258759/www/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-06-21T21:13:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Instagramconnect/Model/Source/Instagram/User.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/7/w258759/www/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-06-21T21:13:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Instagramconnect/Model/Source/Instagram/User.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/7/w258759/www/app/code/local:/home/7/w258759/www/app/code/community:/home/7/w258759/www/app/code/core:/home/7/w258759/www/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /home/7/w258759/www/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

If i reisntall the plugin , it works..

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You have to make sure that the module is completely removed from the codebase so check if there are any .phtml files still in the system... also make sure any additional tables have been removed.

Comment: Also clear your compiler store and then your cache and recompile if you have the compiler turned on. Also, after removing the module, you did clear the cache the first time round?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like instagram added own attribute to products with custom attribute source.

You need remove this attribute in mysql table `eav_attribute`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Magento did not have an uninstall feature to properly uninstall a module. When you remove a module in app/etc/modules/name_of_extension.xml, it does not remove the module at all, it just disable the module.

If you want to remove a module completely you need to check what table, attribute or data have been inserted in the database when the module was installed and remove this table, attribute or data in the database.

For you case Instagram added its own attribute with attribute source "Instagramconnect/Source_Instagram_User.php" something like that in the eav_attribute table, but it did not deleted when remove the module as I have explained above.

You need to delete the attribute that instagram added in the eav_attribute table.

Answer (score 0):

When uninstalling a module / extension make sure to take the following steps:

- make sure to remove the xml file from `app/etc/modules/name_of_extension.xml` this makes sure that Magento does not 'see' the extension anymore
- Make sure to turn of the compiler if its on, this can be checked by going to System->Tools->Compilation and make sure its disable
- Make sure to clear the cach this can be done by going to System->Cache Management

If these don't work, then I suspect that the extension overwrote a core file, if this is the case we would need to find it and replace it with the original.